# How can I add a table to a boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot

```
I used this code to produce a boxplot:
x1 <- rnorm(500)
y1 <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 500, replace=T)
boxplot(x1 ~ y1)
```

I would like to add a table to my plot, however I am unsure of the code I can use to do this:

```
   A  B
1 26 63
2 64 64
3 54 26
4 98 82
5 95  3
> dput(temp)
structure(list(A = c(26, 64, 54, 98, 95), B = c(63, 64, 26, 82, 
3)), .Names = c("A", "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
5L))
```

is a function to do this as I didn't see one in the boxplot documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420980/adding-a-table-of-statistics-to-a-boxplot-in-r  Check `addtable2plot` from `plotrix`

Answer (score 0):

here is a manual solution using `base R`.

```
  x1 <- rnorm(500)
  y1 <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 500, replace=T)

par(mar=c(4,4,4,6),xpd=TRUE)
boxplot(x1 ~ y1)

legend('topright',inset=c(-0.275,0),
c("     A  B",
  "1 26 63",
  "2 64 64",
  "3 54 26",
  "4 98 82",
  "5 95  3"))
```

[image]